# How to disable html5 audio element play/pause button

Tags: javascript, html, audio

What is the way to disable or prevent events from the play/pause button in the html5 audio element?

I am trying something like this:

```
document.getElementById(id).addEventListener("pause", function() {
    $(this).trigger("play");
});
```

This works when alone, but my problem is that I would like to control the play/pause when clicking on the div where the audio element is in:

```html
<div id="my_div">
    <audio controls id="my_audio">
        <source src="my_song.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    </audio>
</div>
```

```js
var is_playing;
$("#my_div").click(function () {
    if (is_playing) {
        $('#my_audio').trigger("pause");
        is_playing = false;
    } else {
        $('#my_audio').trigger("play");
        is_playing = true;
    }
});
```

so this causes conflict when I use the pause/play buttons of the audio element. So, I am searching a way to prevent the event of the play/pause audio element control (but not the whole controls as I need to use the seekbar and volume).

Comment: _"my problem is that I control the audio with something else"_ What is "something else"? Can you create stacksnippets to demonstrate?

Comment: With this code, play and pause invokes continuously... I doubt this is what you are looking for..

Comment: @guest271314 I added information of what I would like exactly to do.

Comment: @Rayon yes sorry, I removed the pause on play it was indeed infinite looping

Comment: @jck, What is the issue then ?

Comment: @Rayon The issue is that when I click the play/pause button it fires 2 events: 1 on the div and 1 on the play button, thus this not work as expected.

Comment: _"The issue is that when I click the play/pause button it fires 2 events: 1 on the div and 1 on the play button"_ How is this possible? Is there additional event listener attached to `#my_audio` element?

Comment: This is really bad UX design.. the reason why is because on clients that don't run JavaScript, you'll have a big play button (that I'm assuming you prefer the user to click on rather than the native one) that will do nothing, and then they'll have a video element that they can't play or pause.

Comment: TY @PatrickRoberts you are right, hopefully the solution works well without JS too (I just tested it now). That's because the deactivation is done by JS too, so if there's no JS the big button still works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`play` and `pause` are not jQuery methods. Try calling `.play()`, `.pause()` on `<audio>` element

```
$(function() {
  var is_playing;
  $("#my_div").click(function(e) {
    // if `e.target` is not `<audio>` element
    if(e.target.tagName !== "AUDIO") {
      if (is_playing) {
        $('#my_audio')[0].pause();
        is_playing = false;
      } else {
        $('#my_audio')[0].play();
        is_playing = true;
      }
    } else {
      e.stopPropagtion()
    }
  });
});
```

plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/l5NejZ4rvxTZLPghkFWF?p=preview

Comment: TY @guest271314, but this works the same way as my code where I use the triger() method, so it doesn't help. The issue I have then is that when I click the play/pause button of the audio element controls, it fires 2 events: 1 on the div and 1 on the play button, thus this not work as expected.

Comment: @jck Can you create a stacksnippets, plnkr http://plnkr.co to demonstrate?

Comment: @jck _" The issue I have then is that when I click the play/pause button of the audio element controls, it fires 2 events: 1 on the div and 1 on the play button"_ Is another click event attached to `#my_div` element which does not appear at Question? See plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/l5NejZ4rvxTZLPghkFWF?p=preview

Comment: I saw your example, in which you can experiment the behavior I am searching to get rid of: If you click the word "click" in the div, it triggers the event ok, then try to click the play button of the audio element, you will see that you will need to click 2 times, because it triggers the div click + the actual button click, so it make pause and play at the same time and doesn't work. (You can see well on Firefox)

Comment: TYVM @guest271314 I was searching in this direction with the stopPropagation() event method, but didn't thought about checking target tagname. It works very good now.